# What if I want a free-standing function?

Tags: c#, oop

Is there any way to write a free-standing function in `C#`? I need a function but I don't consider it a member of any existing `class` and I don't see any point of writing

```
public abstract class HolderForFunctionsThatIDontKnowWhereElseToPut
{
    MyReturnType MyFuction ( ... ) { ... } 
}
```

Comment: You cannot have a static abstract class.  You can however have a static class, with static methods

Comment: From what I've seen, people usually put those in classes named `Utils` or `Utilities`. But before doing that, I'd first wonder why said method does not fit in my current architecture, seems like a code smell.

Comment: .Net is an object oriented programming language. What you ask for is a concept of Procedural Programming.

Comment: @OguzOzgul C++ is object-oriented but allows standalone functions, including `main ()`.

Comment: @SubparWebDev perhaps you need to read up on the the difference between `C++ and C#` as well as understand `OOP` there are things that you can do in `C programming or Delphi` that you can't do in C# for example `Delphi is Multiple Inheritance and Multiple Interface vs C# which is Single Inheritance and Multiple Interface` perhaps you need to know the can's and can not's of the language as well

Comment: Yes, you can do it with C++, which is renamed from "C with Classes" to C++ in 1983. C# on the other hand is intended to be object oriented from the beginning.

Comment: Static methods are basically free standing functions.  And you can use static imports to refer to the function without the qualifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can't have a function without a class/struct.

You can only have a function(method) inside a class or struct.

See: [Why Doesn't C# Implement "Top Level" Methods? (Eric Lippert)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx)

Comment: That link says "we make it easier to reason about the meaning of an unqualified identifier used in an invocation context," but I disagree

Comment: @SubparWebDev -- Wow, if ever I've seen a comment ripe for elaboration, yours is it.

Comment: @SubparWebDev And had you been a principle developer of the C# language team when it was being designed, then that would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As @Habib pointed out you do need a 'container' for a method, so you could do:

```
public static class HolderForFunctionsThatIDontKnowWhereElseToPut
{
    public static MyReturnType MyFuction ( ... ) { ... } 
}
```

And you call it like this for example:

```
public class UseStaticMethods
{
    public MyReturnType NewFuction ( ... ) 
    { 
        ... 
        return HolderForFunctionsThatIDontKnowWhereElseToPut.MyFuction(...);
    } 
}
```